# C# Linq question

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am desperately trying to understand linq and now I have a concrete example of what I want to do (and fail):

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", (from myaddresses[x].PostalNr where x => myaddresses[x].SortType == "110" ))
```

`myaddress` is a dictionary of `OneAddress` objects (my own object) and that object contains the properties `SortType` and `PostalNr`.

I thought I didn't need a loop to do the above, but when the above is rewritten to work it might only take the first hit it gets or?

The questions I want to perform is:
For each entry in the dictionary that has `SortType` set to 110, print out it's postal number.

Comment: Try posting on stackoverflow

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: @TomSquires **["Cross-posting is frowned upon..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a step-by-step walkthrough of one approach to this.

To setup the sample data (based on your question) we have the `OneAddress` class:

```
class OneAddress
{
    public string PostalNr { get; set; }
    public string SortType { get; set; }
}
```

This is in a `Dictionary` so we then have:

```
var myAddresses = new Dictionary<int, OneAddress>();
myAddresses.Add(1, new OneAddress() { PostalNr = "123", SortType = "101" });
myAddresses.Add(2, new OneAddress() { PostalNr = "124", SortType = "110" });
myAddresses.Add(3, new OneAddress() { PostalNr = "125", SortType = "101" });
myAddresses.Add(4, new OneAddress() { PostalNr = "126", SortType = "110" });
myAddresses.Add(5, new OneAddress() { PostalNr = "127", SortType = "110" });
```

First, a basic Linq query to get all dictionary entries:

```
var results = from a in myAddresses
            select a;
```

This returns an `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is a `KeyValuePair<int, OneAddress>` (same as our Dictionary).

As stated, you only want the `PostalNr` not the `KeyValuePair` so we change our query to:

```
var results = from a in myAddresses
            select a.Value.PostalNr;
```

The `Value` contains the `OneAddress` object, and we get only the property we need (in an `IEnumerable<T>`).

However this is for all items in the collection; we can now add our filter.

```
var results = from a in myAddresses
             where a.Value.SortType == "110"
            select a.Value.PostalNr;
```

Now we're getting the `PostalNr` for any `OneAddress` in the Dictionary where `SortType` is `"110"`, and that only leaves printing the results to the console screen.

As highlighted in other answers, `Console.WriteLine()` doesn't work with an enumerable list of strings, so we can enumerate the items with:

```
foreach (string postalNr in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(postalNr);
}
```

Or (if we're using System.Collections.Generic) we can do it on one line with:

```
results.ToList().ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p));
```

Answer (score 2):

The LINQ query you're looking for takes the form:-

```
from <item> in <collection> where <item.someclause> select <item.targetfield>
```

That will return an `IEnumerable<targetfieldtype>` which `Console.WriteLine` doesn't handle.

If the type is a string as it is here you can then apply `string.join()` to concatenate it into a single string.

Like this:-

```
 Console.WriteLine
 (
     string.Join
     (
         "\r\n", 
         from address in Addresses
         where address.SortType=="110"
         select address.PostalNr
     )
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment, because my reputation is to low.

Your problem is not linq itself but how you use it. What you are doing is printing one line. This line will contain the value of the ToString call on a list/collection/linq result. I think it might help you if you don't try to put everything in one line. The error should be obvious if you extract the linq query from the write line.

I don't have an IDE here at my workplace, so I can't confirm my code works, but what you want to do is basically:

```
var addresses = (from myaddresses[x].PostalNr where x => myaddresses[x].SortType == "110" )
addresses.each(Console.WriteLine)
```